# which reports service should I use?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 , developing a windows app.

I want to create some simple reports. I am confused about which reports should I use in the application.

The reports which are available in the Visual Studio or the crystal reports.

what are the advantage of report over each other ? 
I am working on reports after long time so, can I get some simple links, so I can understand workflow of it.

Answer (score 0):

- Crystal Reports seems well documented, more ressources available than Microsoft Reporting
- Huge API in CR (just try to print a Microsoft Reporting-report without preview, that's ridiculous!)
- Crystal Reports somehow slower than Microsoft Reporting with huge amount of data
- Designing reports against custom BusinessObjects is really worse (Wizard isn't even able to "see" objects in another project!) in Crystal Reports
- Crystal Reports's preview integration into our apps is much better than in Microsoft Reporting (just try to make your own toolbar!)
- Microsoft Reporting's integration in the dev environment is superior to CR (which's habit to implement it's own DB-connection is bad taste)
- Both seem to lack designers, our users can use at runtime from within our apps (not external!) to manipulate reports which we prefer to store in the DB (seems to be quite easy with Microsoft Reporting as it's only XML to be stored!) for better managability and deployment.